# Was a "new world religion" memorandum signed in Strasbourg in June 2014?

Tags: religion, sexuality, education, ukraine

There is a document which is shared on the internet these days. I saw it in Romanian language and then searching a bit, I found it in English as well: it refers to a "memorandum" *signed in Strasbourg* containing a list of weird rules which they say they're going to be implemented in different dates in the future.

I quickly read it, but it looks to me like a non-credible thingy. However, I have many friends who tend to believe it. In our country, this appeared on sites I don't trust.

Was such a "Memorandum", coming in effect May 1st 2016, effectively signed in Strasbourg on 25-29 June 2014 as described?

The Romanian version contains way more articles. I created a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw/Rqnfsm2M) containing the Romanian version (which appeared on multiple sites, but the top one is [this](http://www.apologeticum.ro/2016/03/super-memorandumul-si-noua-super-religie-masonica-mondiala-si-biserica-in-perioada-2016-2020/)). Using Google Translate, you can read [the translated version here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ro&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=ro&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2Fraw%2FRqnfsm2M&edit-text=&act=url). The Greek version appears [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/305838955/%CE%A6%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%97-%CE%99%CF%83%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%B4%CF%89%CF%83%CE%B7-%CE%A4%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%A0%CE%91%CE%9D%CE%A4%CE%A9%CE%9D).

For reference, I will leave here two screenshots (downloaded from [here](https://www.gloria.tv/text/CL6ssdZ3PMZzRGxyTtPrEXZee)) of the English version (which seems to not contain *all* the articles which appear in the Romanian version, linked above).

Is this document genuine? Eventually, how can one prove to someone that this is not true?

Few months ago (when this appeared on the internet), I saw many people talking about and believing it. I do believe the passing of time will show this is not genuine (for example, we are already in December, 2016 and there is no *Cancellation of national holidays and exibitions*–Art 6).

> [image]
>
> [image]

<sub>Initially, I asked this on [`christianity.stackexchange.com`](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/52508/9158), but I think asking it here would be good too.</sub>

Comment: When you ask "if this is a credible (at least official/true) document", which document are you referring to? The one you posted? The [Ukrainian Orthodox Greek Catholic Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Orthodox_Greek_Catholic_Church) (established 2009, "presently in exile"), which it purports to come from, has [English-language content on their website](http://vkpatriarhat.org.ua/en), where they expound their views on many things. Do you just want to know if this is really their opinion?

Comment: From my experience, Europeans would often use "signed in Strasbourg" as a short meaning that something was enacted or agreed upon by the EU parliament (which resides in Strasbourg). I suspect that's the case here.

Comment: I find @DanGetz's comments confusing. It seems obvious that there is an alleged "Memorandum" being quoted and OP wants to know if such a thing exists, and if not who invented it. However I am guessing the answer to this lies somewhere in the Eastern European Internet.

Comment: @Avery you're probably right; I was probably just confusing myself. The phrases "this Memorandum has never been published" and "[its plans] are to be secretly ratified" are what really worry me. I might be misunderstanding "never been published", but it sounds to me almost like if someone *does* find an official public document, then that's by definition not "*the* Memorandum", as that one is secret.

Comment: This document is from the "Byzantine Catholic Patriarchate", which appears to be an Orthodox reincarnation of the Landover Baptist Church.  Their web site http://vkpatriarhat.org.ua/en/ gives a pretty good flavor of their views - conservative theology, denouncement of popes, bishops, cardinals.  Opposition to other religions, gay rights, and "microchips".  Given what's on their website, my assumption would be that the mysterious memorandum "signed in Strasbourg" exists only in their imaginations.

Comment: @Mark That's an opinion, not a statement of fact.

Comment: @Avery - Hence the phrase "my assumption would be..."

Comment: The source is https://apokalypsisnow.blogspot.ru/2015/04/blog-post.html and a Greek Snopes-type sight says it is fake here: http://ellinikahoaxes.gr/2016/01/09/%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%80%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%B9-%CF%85%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BC%CE%BD%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BF-%CE%AE-memorandum/

Comment: Thank you for feedback and edits! I added a link to the Romanian version which was shared by some of my friends and tried to make the question even clearer.

Comment: This smells very much like the protocols of the elders of zion

Comment: Just reading this list makes it seem pretty fake. It has all the points you would say if you were against something ("Dismissal of many professors at various levels of education"). If this was true *it wouldn't be written like that*. It would probably say "Redundancy" or "Staff restructuring" or something along those lines.  They certainly would not admit "(note: it is not about security but about control)". Unless they're following the Hollywood evil overlord script.